# Perform arithmetic matrix operators if it meets criteria in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, operators, logical-operators

I have three matrices (ignore the values, they are just for illustration). `a`,`b`, and `c` are of the same variables (they have the same columns/variables and "positioning", but measure different things)

```
# my actual mat is 120x80
a = rbind(c(1,1,2,3,1), c(2,2,3,1,2), c(3,3,1,2,1)) 
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    2    3    1
[2,]    2    2    3    1    2
[3,]    3    3    1    2    1

# my actual mat is 120x80    
b = rbind(c(0.8,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9), c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.6), c(0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.9))
b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.8  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
[2,]  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.7  0.6
[3,]  0.8  0.9  0.7  0.6  0.9

# my actual mat 120x80
c = rbind(c(0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1), c(0.3,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1), c(0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3))
c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.2  0.1
[2,]  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.1
[3,]  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.3
```

We take rows from `b`and rows from `c`

```
If 1 in a[1,] then b[1,]-c[1,], else -c[1,]
If 2 in a[1,] then b[1,]-c[1,], else -c[1,]    or simply 0-c[1,]
If 3 in a[1,] then b[1,]-c[1,], else -c[1,]

d.row1 (a 3x80 matrix)
rownames(drow1)<-c("1","2","3")
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
1  0.7  0.5 -0.3 -0.2  0.8
2 -0.1 -0.1  0.4 -0.2 -0.1
3 -0.1 -0.1 -0.3  0.6 -0.1
```

Notice that `d.row1[1,1]`, `d.row1[1,2]` and `d.row1[1,5]` have the classification 1 in `a[1,]` while the others values in row 1 had the values of 2 or 3. Hence, we performed the operation `b[1,]-c[1,]` instead of `-c[1,]`.

It looks like this:

[image]

Similarly, for row `a[2,]`

```
If 1 in a[2,] then b[2,]-c[2,], else -c[2,]
If 2 in a[2,] then b[2,]-c[2,], else -c[2,]    or simply 0-c[2,]
If 3 in a[2,] then b[2,]-c[2,], else -c[2,]

d.row2 (a 3x80 matrix)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
1 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.5 -0.1
2  0.3  0.5 -0.1 -0.2  0.5
3 -0.3 -0.2  0.7 -0.2 -0.1
```

Notice that `d.row1` and `d.row2` come from row 1 and row 2 of `a`,`b`, and `c`, respectively.

I want to create a list for every row in `a`,`b`, and `c`. In total, 120 data frames in a list (because I have 120 rows in the other matrices).

I am thinking `for` loops or similar might useful for my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic operation can be computed using (for row 1 of `a`)

```
d.row1 <-  b[rep(1, 3), ] * outer(1:3, a[1,], "==") - c[rep(1, 3), ]
```

The list can be done using `lapply` - the other options don't give options for the right input/output (`tapply` requires a vector input, `apply` only allows a matrix output).

Here's the end result:

```
d <- lapply(1:nrow(a), function(i) {
  c[rep(i,3),]* outer(1:3, a[i,], "==") - c[rep(i,3),]
})

> d
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.7  0.5 -0.3 -0.2  0.8
[2,] -0.1 -0.1  0.4 -0.2 -0.1
[3,] -0.1 -0.1 -0.3  0.6 -0.1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.5 -0.1
[2,]  0.3  0.5 -0.1 -0.2  0.5
[3,] -0.3 -0.2  0.7 -0.2 -0.1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] -0.2 -0.3  0.6 -0.2  0.6
[2,] -0.2 -0.3 -0.1  0.4 -0.3
[3,]  0.6  0.6 -0.1 -0.2 -0.3
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. The first row of `[[1]]` is correct, however, the other rows do not perform the same operations. Using `[[1]]` as an example. `[2,]` and `[3,]` should perform the operations from `a[1,]`, `b[1,]` and `c[1,]`. Similarly, all rows in `[[2]]` should perform operations based on `a[2,]`, `b[2,]` and `c[2,]`

Comment: Thank you! I will wait patiently :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Seems like the issue was resolved when I had to call them as.matrix again. Apparently, one of my matrices werent a matrix.